# Access violation when compiling in debug

Tags: debugging, exception, c++builder, access-violation

I'm trying to profile a **C++** project in **Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010**. To do this I wanted to use **AQTime**, but I'm running into a bit of a problem.

I can compile and run the application in **release** mode. But when I compile in **debug** mode, using the settings mentioned at http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/18053/, I get an **access violation**.

> ... faulted with message: 'access
>   violation at 0x062324bd: read of
>   address 0x62324bd'. Process stopped.
>   Use Step or Run to continue.

It seems to come when I load a bunch of dll's at the startup. But since it goes well in release mode I can't seem to figure out what could be the cause.
When the access violation occurs I get thrown out into assembly and that isn't one of the languages I'm fluent in ;)

**EDIT :** When scanning the .exe with **Dependency Walker** I get a message saying that the following files can't be found

```
CC32100MT.DLL
INET140.BPL
RTL140.BPL
VCL140.BPL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

Could this be the problem somehow? Are these debugspecific or is **Dependency Walker** not giving me correct information? The same files are said to be missing when I try a release compiled version to.

I'm running on Windows 7 x64, if that could be part of the issue. I have had problems before with the **symlink-look-alike** *(user/AppData/Local...)* that MS used for some folders. Notably when I ran an apache server and the htdocs folder actually wasn't located where the server thought it was (and where it appeared to be) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling **dynamic rtl** which can be found in the C++ builder linker options pane?

Comment: Nice, that worked... What is it? My guess would be *Dynamic Runtime Library* or something like that :)
Either including the runtime in the .exe or linking it dynamicly. Or is it something totally different?

Comment: Dynamic RTL specifies whether the linker should use static or dynamic linking of the runtime library. By unchecking it you specify that the linker should link the runtime library statically. This enables you to run the executable without the need for the runtime dll's, but increases the file size.